# javascript regex number range format check

Tags: javascript, regex, number-formatting

I want to check whether given input is valid integer range.

```
[0-9]-{1}[0-9]
```

The above regex not working for some cases.

Example:
    10 // false. - working as expected
    10-20 // true. - working as expected
    h-g // false. - working as expected
    10-20- // true. - should be false
    10-20-30 // true. - should be false

**Update 2: Check for comma(,) separated input**

Now the same input text field can allow comma(,) separated input as well. Eg. 10,20,30 also allowed. `rangePattern = new RegExp('^[0-9]*,[0-9]*$')`; is not allowing me to give more than one comma. How to allow repentance.

Example:
     10,20 valid.
     10,20,30 valid.
     10,20, invalid.
     10,20-30 invalid.

**Update 3: regex `/^(\d+,)*\d+$/` not working for input 10,,,20**
How to resolve this?

**Solved:**
   {1} - allow only once.
    regex should be `/^(\d+,{1})*\d+$/`

Comment: In addition to the examples, you might wanna define (in words) what the expected range is...for example, negative number to positive number `-10-20`? what about `20-10`?

Comment: the problem statement increased complexity by allowing float number as well. I have modified the regex to allow integer / float numbers  `/^(\s*\d+|\d*\.\d+\s*,{1})+\s*\d+|\d*\.\d+\s*$/`. This is working for all type of input except one certain format. Example. for input 1,2.5,3 it fails. Actually it should pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `regex` only check for substring/contains.

Use anchors `^`: starts with and `$`: ends with.

```
/^\d+-\d+$/
```

**Explanation:**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `^`: Starts with
3. `\d+`: Matches one or more numbers
4. `-`: Matches `-` literal
5. `$`: Ends with

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7tyg7dqd/)

```html
<input onblur="alert(/^\d+-\d+$/.test(this.value))">
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sL4pW5/1)

---

**Update**

```
var rangePattern = new RegExp('/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*$/');
pass = rangePattern.test(rangeValue);
```

You don't need `/` delimiters when you use `RegExp` constructor.

Use

```
var rangePattern = new RegExp('^[0-9]*-[0-9]*$');
```

---

**Update 2**

To match comma-separated numbers:

```
/^(\d+,+)*\d+$/g
```

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kU1mL7/2)

Comment: i would also point out that `*` quantifier means 0 or more so e.g. `-` `2-` `-2` all match.  Also so does `100-10`.  I mostly blame OP's lack of clarity on requirements though.

Comment: var rangePattern = new RegExp('/^[0-9]*-[0-9]*$/');
     
     pass = rangePattern.test(rangeValue);

it returns false for input: 10-20

Comment: I think this counts as the most gratuitous use of an un–asked for library in an answer. e.g. demo `<input onblur="alert(/^\d+-\d+$/.test(this.value))">`.

Comment: @RobG That is just for Live Demonstration purpose

Comment: The comment I posted can be placed as a live demo too. In one line. ;-)

Comment: excellent.. working fine. Since I used `new RegExp`, was not working, now used your code snippet. working as expected. thanks a lot @Tushar

Comment: @CrayonViolent No, these are all invalid. You can also check this in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7tyg7dqd/)

Comment: Now the same input text field can allow comma `,` separated input as well. Eg. 10,20,30 also allowed. `rangePattern = new RegExp('^[0-9]*,[0-9]*$')`; is not allowing me to give more than one comma. How to allow repentance. Eg. 10,20 valid. 10,20,30 valid. 10,20, invalid. 10,20-30 invalid.

Comment: @SureshRajagopal `^(\d+,)*\d+$` See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU1mL7/1)

Comment: @Tushar.. for input 10,,,20, it is not working. How to resolve this?

Comment: @SureshRajagopal add + after , in regex. `^(\d+,+)*\d+$`

Comment: @SureshRajagopal You should create another question instead of updating the same again and again as your request for `,` separated is completely different than the first question

Comment: @SureshRajagopal OR you could actually write out what you actually want the pattern to match, since you keep adding requirements to it